How to validate 3rd party Outh2 JWT in Laravel?
I'm using an external identity provider to authenticate users, create a SPA client, and get JWT token from outside.
My current API service is written by Laravel and it uses a Passport package. It receives every request with a bearer Access Token (JWT). In the current system, the Passport client handles all token transactions. Due to the system change, user authentications need to be done through SSO. In this case, I think I need to disable the Passport package.
My question is how to validate identity provider(3rd party) JWTs every request in Laravel.

You can verify the JWT signature based on a consumer secret that the SSO provider should be providing you with. Check https://jwt.io it's got basically everything you need to know on JWTs
